# Deleting range partition in db2

Tags: db2, range, database-partitioning

I have a db2 table which was originally created with range partitioning on two of the columns, but now I feel it unnecessary to have the range partitioning.
How do I remove range partitioning from the table without deleting the data already present in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that (other than creating a new table without the partitions and copying all the data over there - this can be tricky if you have foreign key constraints...).

This is one of those DB2 concepts where you have to decide what you want at creation time.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will just export the data, recreate the table and then import the data back. But my table has about 70000 rows. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You don't say what version of DB2 you are using or what platform you're on, but in DB2 9.7 on Linux/UNIX/Windows you can use the ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE stored proc to effect this change while keeping the table online.